# MVC 3 Exception: Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject

I have MVC 3 app with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326945/no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object) same problem. I use Ninject for dependency injection. I cannot trace which controller has a problem, it broke yesterday and I have spent an entire day trying to locate. There are over 60 controllers in the application. The exception cannot be caught or debugged nor the trace provide any meaningful clue as to the problematic source controller. No action for any controller can be accessed without this exception being thrown.

Has anyone any idea how I can determine the actual controller having the problem?

Thanks

Inner Exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
```

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2()
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a()
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust[TResult](Func`1 func)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: `No action for any controller can be accessed without this exception being thrown.`. It sounds like something you're injecting in _every_ controller or an action filter that is used in all controllers is broken (ie missing a dependency). A single broken controller should not break your whole system.

Comment: Hm, this may be nothing since I'm not sure what the stack trace would look like if it's actually using NInject to resolve the controller, but to me it looks like it's using the default activator instead of NInject. Are you sure NInject is correctly registered?

Comment: Yes, definitely not using Ninject. See the line in the inner exception that says `System.Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: Thanks for replies. We traced it to the Ninject assemblies not being deployed since a recent build. It would have been more helpful to have a FileNotFoundException rather than this parameterless constructor exception.

Comment: What's probably happening is that Ninject can't create the controller and returns `null` to the `DefaultControllerFactory`. Ninject returns `null` in that case, because the `IDependencyResolver` contract requires it to. The controller factory in that case falls back to the default behavior, which is using `Activator.CreateInstance`. The solution is: verify whether Ninject can create every controller in your system. Either do this in a automated test, or during application startup. Here is a [related question about Web API](http://bit.ly/1aMbBW1). MVC has a similar architecture as Web API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems NInject either is not registered correctly to resolve anything at all, or it cannot resolve any of your controller types. From the source of MVC3, this is the call to `Activator.CreateInstance` that shows in the stack trace;

```
return (IController)(_resolverThunk().GetService(controllerType) ??
                     Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType));
```

In other words, it will not call `Activator.CreateInstance` at all unless the controller cannot be resolved correctly by NInject.

In other words, you should probably stop hunting the problem in your controllers, and start checking up on the NInject registration. Simplest first step would be to make a dead stupid controller with a default constructor, set a breakpoint in the constructor and see that the stack trace reflects that the constructor is being called by NInject. If it's not, NInject is not registered correctly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. No breakpoint in a constructor ever gets hit.

Comment: @GordonHickley Not even when using a parameterless constructor on your test controller? Still getting the same stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off of Joachim above:

Defining the NInjectControllerFactory is not enough, you must also make sure to register the controller in global.asax.cs

I was getting the same issues - i.e. the Ninject class was defined in Project>Infrastructure>NinjectControllerFactory.cs yet no breakpoints were being hit when compiling and navigating to simplistic routes.  The following line must be added to Application_Start():

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that injected class is abstract. 
this type of class can not be instantiated.